# Taking information from other apps (specifically iPhone's Phone app)

Tags: iphone, tracking, usage-statistics, minute

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to track the usage of a phone's minutes from an iPhone app. I think there must be a solution since iData Usage can track the data a phone has used, there must be a similar solution for minutes. Does anyone know if this is possible or how to achieve this?

Thank you,

Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps that track data usage probably work by examining log files. For example, use the Console app on your Mac to take a look at /private/var/log/daily.out and you'll see that the system logs daily totals for inbound and outbound packets on each network interface. iOS shares a lot with MacOS X under the hood, so it's very likely that

Does a similar log file exist on iPhone, and does it keep track of phone calls? I don't know. If it exists, can you get access to that data? I don't know. But analyzing log files seems like a promising avenue to explore.

You also might want to explore whether AT&T and/or Verizon offer any sort of API that lets you request minutes used, minutes remaining, etc. They must provide some service along those lines since the user can request that information in the Settings app and receive the answer via SMS. Whether you can get access to that service is another question.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I will give this a try and see if I can figure out any solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of this possibility and thus it's not possible (AFAIK).

Comment: Everything physically and mathematically possible, is possible in a iPhone. If Apple allow you to do it or not, is whole another story

Comment: A taut tautology. I salute you.